# Add select attribute conditionally in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I want to add aria-describedby attribute only if value is present otherwise to add that attribute.

Need code to make this attribute conditional.

here is my dropdown code:

```
<select
    id={field.id}
    name={field.name}
    value={field.value}
    aria-describedby=this.getAriaDescribedby(valid)}
    aria-required={field.required ? 'true' : null}
    {...inputEventHandlers}
/>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about defining a function that returns an object:

```
const conditionalValues = () => {
            if (field.value) {

                return { "aria-describedby": this.getAriaDescribedby(field.valid) };
            }
            return {};
        };
```

Then use that inside the select:

```
<select
    id={field.id}
    name={field.name}
    value={field.value}
    {...conditionalValues()}
    aria-required={field.required ? "true" : null}
    {...inputEventHandlers}
/>
```

You can extend that function to return the needed properties, otherwise returns an empty object.